# How to Update data from One Sheet to another sheet in Google sheet on the basis of Criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with two tabs. The first tab is named "Home" and Second Tab is named "Python NBA FD Salaries". I have made a search record box using drop-down by "Nick Name" and the Vlookup formula. Here is the link to Google Sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WXyfK1GW6VnEIjBYBw9SLjQ46UEaHs3CgLaOkOFXBlk/edit?usp=sharing

I have put three buttons on the sheet. The button is (Tick) Button, When I press this button the record in column-G on the sheet "Python NBA FD Salaries" should be updated against the name I select from the dropdown in the "Home Sheet". So, for example, If I select "Jarrell Brantley" from the drop-down list in the "Home" sheet and Press the (Tick) button, the record against this nickname in the Sheet "Python NBA FD Salaries" Column-G should be increased by +5. Let say the value in column-G against "Jarrell Brantley" is 17 (In my sheet) and when I press the (Tick) Button it should be 17+5 = 22. Similarly, If I press the (Lock) Button it should be +100 and if I press the (Lock) Button, it should be -100 from the existing value. I am using the following script but is not affecting properly as I am looking for.

```
function plus() {
ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
s=ss.getActiveSheet()
var currVal=s.getRange("A1").getValue()
var plusVal= currVal +5
s.getRange("A1") .setValue(plusVal)
}
```

Please suggest to me where I am getting wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Exactly how is it not working? Does it do anything? Does it show an error?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 is not working and updating the results in the Target sheet row. while is also not showing any error.

Comment: you need to put `let` before your variables.

Comment: why did you choose `A1`. That value will not be in the `A1` cell.

Comment: first, it needs to search that particular row by the nickname, then it needs to update the Column-G value according to the scenario. It is only updating particular cell values like A1 not searching and updating targeted row data.

Comment: OK thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There, try the following:

```js
function getActive ()
{
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
}

function plus(pointAmount = 5, neededNick = getActive().getSheetByName("Home").getRange("C2").getValue()) {
    let sheet = getActive().getSheetByName("Python NBA FD Salaries");
    let headerStrings = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].map(v => v.toString());
    let nickNameColNumber = 1 + headerStrings.indexOf("Nickname");
    let neededNickRowNum = sheet.getRange(1, nickNameColNumber, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().findIndex(row => row[0] === neededNick) + 1;
    let fpCol = 1 + headerStrings.indexOf("FP");
    let fpCell = sheet.getRange(neededNickRowNum, fpCol);
    fpCell.setValue(+fpCell.getValue() + pointAmount);
    Browser.msgBox(`Modified row ${neededNickRowNum} column ${fpCol} adding ${pointAmount} resulting in ${+fpCell.getValue()}`);
}

function minus(pointAmount = 5, neededNick = undefined) { plus(-pointAmount, neededNick); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but brother it is not working. The idea is very simple,
1- The code should get the nickname from the "home" sheet
2- Search the nickname from the second sheet.
3- Select the cell column-G of the matched cell and store the current value of the cell is variable. 
4- Add +5 in the existing cell value, then populate a new value in the same cell. 
5- Finish the updating.

Comment: @AliAhmerRahil, what code does the button execute? Where in the home sheet will the nickname be? I will make it read the cell `C2`.

Comment: Here is full access link. You can check it 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WXyfK1GW6VnEIjBYBw9SLjQ46UEaHs3CgLaOkOFXBlk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am getting this error now. 
Exception: The starting row of the range is too small

Comment: What is the line number?

Comment: I found the problem. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. let me check it plz...hope this will work.

Comment: I believe it would actually do the row above. I just fixed that.

Comment: brother it is not updating the value. now its error free.

Comment: I changed it. It will now display a message saying what it did. Can you run it and tell me what the message says?

Comment: it is displaying following error.
TypeError: getActive(...).getSheet is not a function

Comment: @AliAhmerRahil, oh that was a mistake on my part. I just changed it. You can try it again.

Comment: Thanks, brother. I am really thankful to you for your time and efforts. It really amazing.

Comment: @AliAhmerRahil, it was a pleasure to help. BTW, if you want to take out the alert box which will probably slow you down just take out this line: `Browser.msgBox(``Modified row ${neededNickRowNum} column ${fpCol} adding ${pointAmount} resulting in ${+fpCell.getValue()}``);`

Comment: thanks. I will make sure to remove it if I need.

Answer (score 0):

Support the press button sheet name is [list] and the list to be updated is on sheet [mainlist], you can use for loop since only one value will be update every time you press the button:

```js
function plus() {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var mainSheet=ss.getSheetByName('main');
    var name = mainSheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
    var namelistSheet = ss.getSheetByName('list')
    
    for(var i=2;i<= namelistSheet.getLastRow();i++){
      if(namelistSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue() == name){
        var newValue = namelistSheet.getRange(i,6).getValue() + 5
        namelistSheet.getRange(i,6).setValue(newValue)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: The sheets are actually called "Home" and "Python NBA FD Salaries" so you know.

Comment: @trinalbadger587, ya, i just use other name as i preferred.

Comment: @KinSiang, brother I have tested this code, but it is not working.

Comment: Chang the sheet name should work, I have no issue to update value.